# Running a Node.js API in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a Monorepo which contains a front-end app and a node.js API. I would like to run both the front-end app and the node.js API, in order to run some end-to-end tests. However I can not figure out how to run these two applications before running the tests. Here is my actions file so far.

```
name: Test Client

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Initial Setup
        run: |
          npm install yarn -g
      - name: yarn install, build, and test
        working-directory: client-app
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build
          yarn test
        env:
          CI: true
```

I would like to run an API in a different directory, before running the client-app tests. Is this possible without using a third-party service?

Comment: As you're using Node, the easiest way is probably something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently (e.g. like I set up here: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/ddcc8c98272b2be9efab5499de9c8557a543458e/package.json#L19). You could alternatively look to see whether GitHub Actions supports "backgrounding" a step.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe you post led me to a little bash command "&" which allows to run tasks in the background. for example "yarn start-api &". This means the CI pipeline does not hang on the command. :)

Comment: This is a valid question, i.e. how to start a front-end app and a back-end app together in github action. Not sure why someone downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure the pipeline does not hang on a command by adding "&" to the end of the command: see: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26864#discussioncomment-3253713

For example now I can do:

```
yarn start-api &
yarn start-client &
yarn test
```